# GridBag Layout alignment issue

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I had been practicing GridBagLayout from some time, but still I feel confused when I want desired output. I want this kind of output

[image: GUI Required]

but i mess up creating one on which table is on one side and the two buttons are on other sides. The table gets squeezed.

Can anybody give me code to align the components (buttons and a table) like this. References for components are 
activateServer, addFiles and table

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT** : this is the code which i am using (Short code for illustrating only prob)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class ServerCode extends JFrame
{
    ServerCode()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(10,3);
        JButton addFiles= new JButton("Add files"),activateServer = new JButton("Activate Button");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        add(table,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,6,6, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
        add(addFiles,new GridBagConstraints(1,6,2,1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
        add(activateServer,new GridBagConstraints(6,6,2,1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));

        setSize(700,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ServerCode();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

And its output is :

[image: Problem]

Comment: "Can anybody give me code".... Nope. You can show your attempt and we can help you to the best of our ability.

Comment: Yep, as per @Tdorno's suggestion, by your creating and posting for us your [minimal, runnable, testable program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can see what mistakes you might be making, and thus are better equipped to help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I have added a small code, please check it and help

Answer (score 2):

Heck, I'd just use a BorderLayout for this. Forget GridBagLayout if it is not needed. For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayoutFoo extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;

   public LayoutFoo() {

      JPanel buttonPanel = new  JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Foo"));
      buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Bar"));


      String[] columnNames = {"Mon", "Tues", "Wed"};
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 25);
      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
      scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(table.getPreferredSize());
      // scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize());

      JLabel southLabel = new JLabel("Foobars!");
      southLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
      JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
      southPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
      southPanel.add(southLabel);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
      add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
      int width = PREF_W > superSize.width ? PREF_W : superSize.width;
      return new Dimension(width, superSize.height);
   }


   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      LayoutFoo paintEg = new LayoutFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Smart File Transfer");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the GridBagLayout i believe you need something like this:

```
    add(activateServer,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
    add(addFiles,new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
    add(table,new GridBagConstraints(0,1,2,1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0,0));
```

if you are having problems using the creator of GridBagConstraints you should try using the easier way like in [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java)

for more info try the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)